# Convert System.Windows.Media.SolidColorBrush to Excel.Range.Interior.Color in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, excel, solidcolorbrush

I want to convert System.Windows.Media.SolidColorBrush to Excel.Range.Interior.Color in wpf.
How can I do this?

Comment: You can convert a color to your Range interior color with this in code. System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(mySolidColorBrush.Color); if you want in xaml then you write a valueconverter which does the same thing in the convert method

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I convert System.Windows.Media.SolidcolorBrush to System.Drawing.Color?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3457680/how-do-i-convert-system-windows-media-solidcolorbrush-to-system-drawing-color)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/945808/how-to-convert-excel-range-interior-color-to-system-drawing-color-in-c and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19658064/use-system-drawing-color-to-draw-a-line-in-wpf will be of help to you.